# How to make one of vertically aligned children shrink to width set by other children?

Tags: html, css

### Question

There is an inline container with 2 vertically stacked children. Pictured below:

[image: Current layout]

The top green child should shrink it's width to the width of the bottom orange child, wrapping the text inside itself. The desired layout pictured below:

[image: Layout that I'd like to achieve]

**Question**: How can it be done with CSS alone?

#### Other cases

**Orange container wider than the green one** (picture below). Green stays at it's natural maximum width. Note that even if the solution woulds stretch the green box to 100%, implementing the target solution would be easy by adding an extra container for the green box and then centering the green box inside it.

[image: Orange container wider than the green one]

**Orange box wider than the maxium possible width of the parent** (picture below). Orange should start wrapping.

[image: Orange box wider than the possible width of the parent]

### Notes

- The content of the children is dynamic - the solution needs to work with children of variable width.
- The parent is inline - it's width is not 100%, but rather the width of it's widest child.
- Browser support is of no importance. Solutions can use even CSS Grid.

### Code

#### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/twfky2cr/24/

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fitChild">
    Some long text that I would like to wrap to fit the container size
    set by the orange box
  </div>
  <div class="fullWidthChild">
    This one should set the container size
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.container,
.fitChild,
.fullWidthChild {
  padding: 10px;
}

.fitChild {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;;
}

.fullWidthChild {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Have their width be 100%, and Control the width of the parent?  Or are you looking to make it more dynamic based on the width of the largest or smallest div?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to clarify that. I'll add the notes in the question.

Comment: What if 2 children will have a lot of text? Let's say each children will have 1000 words, then what should  be the width?

Comment: @Observer: Then the parent container should grow until it's as wide as it's parent and then the children should start wrapping.

Comment: @Robert Kusznier, so basically you have max-width for the parent element

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved by css only. But it's easy enough with js

Comment: @Huangism, I agree with you

Comment: Probably it is impossible using CSS alone like you say. But I'm leaving the question open. Maybe someone will come up with a solution and enlighten us all :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial solution for You.

http://jsfiddle.net/twfky2cr/166/

I'm using `display: table` and `width:1px` for cells.

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell wrap">
      Some long text that I would like to wrap to fit the container size
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell nowrap">
      This one should set the container size
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

.table {
  background-color: Black;
  display: table;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1px;
}

.wrap {
  color: white;
  background-color: Green;
  white-space: wrap;
}

.nowrap {
  background-color: Orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Here is a link for a little modfied fiddle, fixing the case when orange box is wider than the green one: http://jsfiddle.net/twfky2cr/163/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kjr9aghp/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.fitChild').width($('.fullWidthChild').width());

});
```

Comment: What if fitChild has less characters then fullWitdthChild?

Comment: Though this solution could work (@Observer noted it needs some small improvements), I'm mainly interested if that's possible using only CSS. That is clarified in the question now.

Answer (score -1):

```
 .container {
   display: inline-flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: black;
 }

 .container,
 .fitChild,
 .fullWidthChild {
   padding: 10px;
   width: 100% !important;
 }

 .mainwrapper{
   max-width:50%;
 }

.fitChild {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;;
}

.fullWidthChild {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}



<div class="container">
  <div class="mainwrapper">
    <div class="fitChild">
      Some long text that I would like to wrap to fit
      the container size set by the orange box
    </div>
    <div class="fullWidthChild">
      This one should set the container size
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add comments what you have changed

Comment: .mainwrapper{

         max-width:50%;
          }

Comment: @RjAdii: It doesn't work when you modify the orange box contents. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/twfky2cr/66/

Comment: @Robert Kusznier please check i have updated this orange box content but it looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/dkb65r73/

Comment: @RjAdii: No, it's stiil missing the point. Increase the table size and the orange box should stay at it's small width, but it does not.